# SocketTimeoutException on discover

Tags: android

I am trying to play with an open source project that found on github.

This project is working with Sockets to communicate with 2 or mode devices...

My problem is when the code is tring to discover the Server (Tablet) i am getting this error:

```
  W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:594)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
     W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:163)
     W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:171)
   W/System.err:     at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:274)
     W/System.err:     at edu.vub.at.commlib.CommLib.discover(CommLib.java:117)
     W/System.err:     at edu.vub.at.nfcpoker.comm.DiscoveryAsyncTask.doInBackground(DiscoveryAsyncTask.java:60)
     W/System.err:     at edu.vub.at.nfcpoker.comm.DiscoveryAsyncTask.doInBackground(DiscoveryAsyncTask.java:35)
     W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
     W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
     W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:189)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
    W/System.err:   ... 12 more
```

My Method is :

```
public static CommLibConnectionInfo discover(Class<?> klass, String broadcastAddress) throws IOException {
        final String targetClass = klass.getCanonicalName();
        Log.e(TAG, "discover: targetClass "+ targetClass);
        Kryo k = new Kryo();
        k.setRegistrationRequired(false);
        k.register(CommLibConnectionInfo.class);
        k.register(UUID.class, new UUIDSerializer());

        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(DISCOVERY_PORT, InetAddress.getByName(broadcastAddress));
        ds.setBroadcast(true);
        ds.setReuseAddress(true);
        ds.setSoTimeout(DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT);
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
        try {

            ds.receive(dp);
            CommLibConnectionInfo clci = k.readObject(new Input(dp.getData()), CommLibConnectionInfo.class);
            if (clci.serverType_.equals(targetClass)) {
                ds.close();
                return clci;
            }
            return null;
        }catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        } finally {
            ds.close();
        }
    }
```

This method make an exception on line : ds.receive(dp);

The App runs on Nexus and Lenovo but on Samsung Devices i am taking this exception

Comment: did you try to increase buffer size? If you have UTF-8 you need 2048 bytes to read 1024 length

Comment: you mean 2048 ?

Comment: yes, DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[2048], 1024);

Comment: @DEADMC is not working i got the same exception :(